# Can I combine a few sub master pages to one main master page?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

In my document I want to have three different headers and five different backgrounds and one footer. Do I need to create a separate master page for each combination of header-background-footer? Or maybe there is a way to apply a few master pages to one regular page? Thanks.

Comment: Well you can give one sub master to a master page. The easiest method would be to just drag one master on top of another master. With that you can technically have as many sub masters as you want, if you chain it by giving each sub master their own sub master. It might not be as easy as I make it sound. In fact, it probably isn't. Just thinking about this made my head hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in total that's 15 different possible configurations. You could definitely create masters for all 15 (16 actually 1 for the footer then drag that master to the other 15). This is probably the easiest method.

I don't think this would be easier than just creating 6 masters (5 background + 1 footer) and then manually adding the desired header to each page.

With so many combinations, no matter how you set things up it'll be a bit complex.

You can apply one master to another master, but I'm unaware of any feature which allows you to apply multiple master pages to a single page.

Comment: Scott, it's the same feature that allows you to apply one master to another master, that also allows more masters to be added to that chain. Let's say we have 5 masters: `Master 1` - `Master 5`. We make `Master 5` the sub master of `Master 4`. We make `Master 4` sub master of `Master 3`. We make `Master 3` sub master of `Master 2`. We make `Master 2` sub master of `Master 1`. Now `Master 1` has 4 sub masters. The rest depends on what content each master has and how it is placed.

Comment: True, it could be handled that way. I'm just not certain it would be *less* confusing. In addition, the stacking order may be an issue unless you carefully plan what master is applied to what master. Using base masters, then creating additional masters for the combinations results in 25 masters (5 background, 3 header, 1 footer + 15 varying combinations)... I don't know that that's better than just setting up 16 with all the combinations. :)

Comment: I didn't say it would be usable in this case. I just wanted to let you know that it's in fact possible to chain masters.

Comment: Cool. I was aware. I was just thinking of the "backgrounds" which could *possibly* limit the  ability to apply masters on top of masters on top of masters.

Comment: Well you were speaking generally in the last paragraph of your answer and so was I in my comment. As a side note, it is very usable method in many many cases, it just doesn't reaally help with this one.